# After adding authentication headers, uploaded file refuses to carry over to the POST route in Express JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am building a simple file upload app in the MEAN stack and have come across an issue. As I am using Passport JS for authentication, I need to intervene the POST procedure, add the appropriate header, and then continue with the POST call.

Here is my index.ejs file with the working AngularJS code:

```
<form ng-submit="addPhoto()" ng-show="isLoggedIn()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="imageFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" name="imageFile" file-model="imageFile">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
</form>
```

angularApp.js backend code:

```
app.factory('photos', ['$http', 'auth', function($http, auth){
  var o = {
    photos: []
  };
  o.create = function(photo) {
    console.log(photo) // <--- this shows the file in the console, that means the file is carried till here
    return $http.post('/photos', photo, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer '+auth.getToken(),
        'Content-Type': undefined
      }
    }).success(function(data){
      o.photos.push(data);
    }).error(function(a) {
      console.log(a);
    });
  };
  return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','photos','auth','fileUpload', function($scope, photos, auth, fileUpload){
  $scope.photos = photos.photos;
  $scope.isLoggedIn = auth.isLoggedIn;
  $scope.addPhoto = function(){
    photos.create($scope.imageFile);
  };
}]);

app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
      var modelSetter = model.assign;

      element.bind('change', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
        });
      });
    }
  };
}]);

app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
  this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
      transformRequest: angular.identity,
      headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
  }
}]);
```

routes\index.js:

```
router.post('/photos', auth, function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req); // <--- the output to this line is below
  var dirname = require('path').dirname(__dirname);
  var filename = req.files.name;
  var path = req.files.path;
  var type = req.files.mimetype;
  var read_stream = fs.createReadStream(dirname + '/' + path);
  var conn = req.conn;
  var Grid = require('gridfs-stream');
  Grid.mongo = mongoose.mongo;
  var gfs = Grid(conn.db);
  var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename: filename
  });
  read_stream.pipe(writestream);
  req.photo.save(function(err, photo){
    if(err){ return next(err); }
    res.json(photo);
  });
});
```

Running this code, I get the following output in the npm console:

```
C:\Users\John\Documents\beta-ios\beta-ios>npm start

> linked@0.0.0 start C:\Users\John\Documents\beta-ios\beta-ios
> node ./bin/www

GET / 200 49.991 ms - 4506
GET /stylesheets/bootstrap.min.css 200 12.465 ms - 122700
GET /javascripts/angularApp.js 200 12.763 ms - 6202
GET /photos 200 24.486 ms - 58
GET /%7B%7Bphoto._id%7D%7D.jpg 404 9.022 ms - 1836
GET /55bd5f88550ddcfc0a3c78cf.jpg 404 17.846 ms - 1836
{ _readableState:
   { objectMode: false,
     highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: null,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: {},
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  socket:
   { _connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      { fd: undefined,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      { objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: true,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      { objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 2268,
     _bytesDispatched: 129753,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:null:3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      { _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 1435,
        _bytesDispatched: 8806,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 100710424,
        parser: [Object],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: null,
        _peername: [Object] },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 100714580,
     parser:
      { '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        _startAt: undefined,
        _startTime: undefined,
        writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
        __onFinished: [Object] },
     _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 50286 } },
  connection:
   { _connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      { fd: undefined,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      { objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: true,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      { objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 2268,
     _bytesDispatched: 129753,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:null:3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      { _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 1435,
        _bytesDispatched: 8806,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 100710424,
        parser: [Object],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: null,
        _peername: [Object] },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 100714580,
     parser:
      { '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        _startAt: undefined,
        _startTime: undefined,
        writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
        __onFinished: [Object] },
     _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 50286 } },
  httpVersionMajor: 1,
  httpVersionMinor: 1,
  httpVersion: '1.1',
  complete: false,
  headers:
   { host: 'localhost:3000',
     connection: 'keep-alive',
     'content-length': '75601',
     pragma: 'no-cache',
     'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
     'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36',
     authorization: 'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NWJkNWRmYjU1MGRkY2ZjMGEzYzc4Y2UiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhdXJhYmgiLCJleHAiOjE0NDM2NTc3NzUsImlhdCI6MTQzODQ3Mzc3NX0.bsro3PeMhD6ElJozOzmoacVNLeq9sSf5URRXR38I3vY',
     'content-type': 'image/jpeg',
     referer: 'http://localhost:3000/',
     'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
     'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
     cookie: 'mongo-express=s%3ALAs78DiMvZdv2D577UjGc3e6.pBf8a1nS7jay2MALZYwtfX5N5qbUPRviz3ATadV8IYA' },
  rawHeaders:
   [ 'Host',
     'localhost:3000',
     'Connection',
     'keep-alive',
     'Content-Length',
     '75601',
     'Pragma',
     'no-cache',
     'Cache-Control',
     'no-cache',
     'Accept',
     'application/json, text/plain, */*',
     'Origin',
     'http://localhost:3000',
     'User-Agent',
     'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.125 Safari/537.36',
     'Authorization',
     'Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1NWJkNWRmYjU1MGRkY2ZjMGEzYzc4Y2UiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhdXJhYmgiLCJleHAiOjE0NDM2NTc3NzUsImlhdCI6MTQzODQ3Mzc3NX0.bsro3PeMhD6ElJozOzmoacVNLeq9sSf5URRXR38I3vY',
     'Content-Type',
     'image/jpeg',
     'Referer',
     'http://localhost:3000/',
     'Accept-Encoding',
     'gzip, deflate',
     'Accept-Language',
     'en-US,en;q=0.8',
     'Cookie',
     'mongo-express=s%3ALAs78DiMvZdv2D577UjGc3e6.pBf8a1nS7jay2MALZYwtfX5N5qbUPRviz3ATadV8IYA' ],
  trailers: {},
  rawTrailers: [],
  _pendings: [],
  _pendingIndex: 0,
  upgrade: false,
  url: '/photos',
  method: 'POST',
  statusCode: null,
  statusMessage: null,
  client:
   { _connecting: false,
     _hadError: false,
     _handle:
      { fd: undefined,
        reading: true,
        owner: [Circular],
        onread: [Function: onread],
        onconnection: null,
        writeQueueSize: 0 },
     _parent: null,
     _host: null,
     _readableState:
      { objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: true,
        sync: false,
        needReadable: true,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        ranOut: false,
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: true,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null,
        resumeScheduled: false },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Object],
        finish: [Function: onSocketFinish],
        _socketEnd: [Function: onSocketEnd],
        drain: [Object],
        timeout: [Function],
        error: [Object],
        close: [Object],
        data: [Function: socketOnData] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     _writableState:
      { objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        needDrain: false,
        ending: false,
        ended: false,
        finished: false,
        decodeStrings: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        length: 0,
        writing: false,
        corked: 0,
        sync: false,
        bufferProcessing: false,
        onwrite: [Function],
        writecb: null,
        writelen: 0,
        bufferedRequest: null,
        lastBufferedRequest: null,
        pendingcb: 0,
        prefinished: false,
        errorEmitted: false },
     writable: true,
     allowHalfOpen: true,
     destroyed: false,
     bytesRead: 2268,
     _bytesDispatched: 129753,
     _pendingData: null,
     _pendingEncoding: '',
     server:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 2,
        _handle: [Object],
        _usingSlaves: false,
        _slaves: [],
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 120000,
        _connectionKey: '4:null:3000' },
     _idleTimeout: 120000,
     _idleNext:
      { _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 1435,
        _bytesDispatched: 8806,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Circular],
        _idleStart: 100710424,
        parser: [Object],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: null,
        _peername: [Object] },
     _idlePrev: { _idleNext: [Circular], _idlePrev: [Object] },
     _idleStart: 100714580,
     parser:
      { '0': [Function: parserOnHeaders],
        '1': [Function: parserOnHeadersComplete],
        '2': [Function: parserOnBody],
        '3': [Function: parserOnMessageComplete],
        _headers: [],
        _url: '',
        socket: [Circular],
        incoming: [Circular],
        maxHeaderPairs: 2000,
        onIncoming: [Function: parserOnIncoming] },
     _paused: false,
     read: [Function],
     _consuming: true,
     _httpMessage:
      { domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        writable: true,
        _last: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: true,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: true,
        _removedHeader: {},
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: false,
        _hangupClose: false,
        _headerSent: false,
        socket: [Circular],
        connection: [Circular],
        _header: null,
        _headers: [Object],
        _headerNames: [Object],
        req: [Circular],
        locals: {},
        _startAt: undefined,
        _startTime: undefined,
        writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
        __onFinished: [Object] },
     _peername: { address: '::1', family: 'IPv6', port: 50286 } },
  _consuming: false,
  _dumped: false,
  next: [Function: next],
  baseUrl: '',
  originalUrl: '/photos',
  _parsedUrl:
   { protocol: null,
     slashes: null,
     auth: null,
     host: null,
     port: null,
     hostname: null,
     hash: null,
     search: null,
     query: null,
     pathname: '/photos',
     path: '/photos',
     href: '/photos',
     _raw: '/photos' },
  params: {},
  query: {},
  res:
   { domain: null,
     _events:
      { prefinish: [Function: resOnFinish],
        end: [Function: onevent],
        finish: [Function: onevent] },
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     output: [],
     outputEncodings: [],
     outputCallbacks: [],
     writable: true,
     _last: false,
     chunkedEncoding: false,
     shouldKeepAlive: true,
     useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
     sendDate: true,
     _removedHeader: {},
     _hasBody: true,
     _trailer: '',
     finished: false,
     _hangupClose: false,
     _headerSent: false,
     socket:
      { _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 2268,
        _bytesDispatched: 129753,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 100714580,
        parser: [Object],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        _peername: [Object] },
     connection:
      { _connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: [Object],
        _parent: null,
        _host: null,
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: true,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: true,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        destroyed: false,
        bytesRead: 2268,
        _bytesDispatched: 129753,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: [Object],
        _idleTimeout: 120000,
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleStart: 100714580,
        parser: [Object],
        _paused: false,
        read: [Function],
        _consuming: true,
        _httpMessage: [Circular],
        _peername: [Object] },
     _header: null,
     _headers: { 'x-powered-by': 'Express' },
     _headerNames: { 'x-powered-by': 'X-Powered-By' },
     req: [Circular],
     locals: {},
     _startAt: undefined,
     _startTime: undefined,
     writeHead: [Function: writeHead],
     __onFinished: { [Function: listener] queue: [Object] } },
  _startAt: [ 100714, 581196550 ],
  _startTime: Mon Aug 03 2015 19:36:03 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time),
  _remoteAddress: '::1',
  body: {},
  secret: undefined,
  cookies: { 'mongo-express': 's:LAs78DiMvZdv2D577UjGc3e6.pBf8a1nS7jay2MALZYwtfX5N5qbUPRviz3ATadV8IYA' },
  signedCookies: {},
  _passport:
   { instance:
      { _key: 'passport',
        _strategies: [Object],
        _serializers: [],
        _deserializers: [],
        _infoTransformers: [],
        _framework: [Object],
        _userProperty: 'user',
        Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
        Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
        Strategy: [Object],
        strategies: [Object] },
     session: {} },
  route:
   { path: '/photos',
     stack: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     methods: { post: true } },
  payload:
   { _id: '55bd5dfb550ddcfc0a3c78ce',
     username: 'john',
     exp: 1443657775,
     iat: 1438473775 } }
POST /photos 500 95.403 ms - 688
```

As a result, I am unable to post the image file. `req.files` returns undefined in `routes\index.js`. Why is my file not passing through?

Comment: Way too much code to sift through. As a generic solution: try using middleware or an AngularJS JWT interceptor that attaches the authorization header to every request.

Comment: @JoshBeam I do have an authentication middleware: `router.post('/photos', auth, function(req, res, next) {`

Comment: Okay cool. Is there anyway you'd be able to narrow down where the problem is? That's a huge console output. Are you getting errors anywhere else, etc.?

Comment: I can provide you with the entire code files, but I am not sure if I can narrow down the post more than I have already done. The console output is not helpful at all. What I did notice, however, is that adding `file: photo` to the `headers` array in angularApp.js shows the photo object in the console, but again, I don't think passing uploaded files inside the header is a good idea.

Comment: Where are you `use()`ing a `multipart/form-data` parsing middleware?

Comment: My app.js file has the following line: `var multer = require('multer');app.use(multer({'dest': './uploads'}).single('photo'));` Although, that doesn't really matter at this point as the uploaded file is being retrieved from angularJS directive, not `multer`.